# Is it possible in a NET Core Web Application to reference another NET Core Web Application project and reuse types and views?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I want to reuse some types, views and scripts from another NET Core Web Application. I have tried to add a reference to the project, and everything seems fine. The types from the other projects get syntax highlighting and everything compiles. But at runtime, when the types are accessed I get exception: FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly {referenced assembly name}.

EDIT: I checked in my projects bin folder and the DLL for the referenced project is there in \bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0{referenced dll}

What could be wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use a shared project. And put all classes there.
I am not sure if content like javascript file can be shared using this type of projects but I think it could be possible.

More references can find here:

- https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/7ca517/shared-project-an-impressive-features-of-visual-studio-201/
- http://rion.io/2017/03/22/sharing-is-caring-using-shared-projects-in-asp-net/